# Eliminar duplicados de columna ID pero mantener valores en nuevas columnas en R

Tags: r

Tengo este `data.frame`:

```
c_dupli <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2), value=c(10,20,30))
```

Mi intención es dejar los `id` únicos, pero mantener los `value` diferentes en otra/s columna/s. El resultado esperado es el siguiente:

```
s_dupli <- data.frame(id=c(1,2), value1=c(10,30), value2=c(20,"NA"))
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora, la forma que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(c_dupli, id ~ rowid(id, prefix = "value"), value.var = "value")
```

Usando `reshape` también podemos hacer esto:

```
# agregamos un numerador por grupo
c_dupli$num <- ave(c_dupli$id, c_dupli$id, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(c_dupli, idvar="id", timevar="num", direction="wide")
```

La salida en todos los casos es similar a esto:

```
  id value1 value2
1  1     10     20
2  2     30     NA
```

Saludos..